# Create a multi-language REST API's in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, language

I have **multi-language** store in `Magento v 2.2.5`

**English**
[image]

**French**
[image]

Now,I have created multiple REST API's, like

- Custom Home Page REST API's
- GET Products, Categories
- Add to cart
- Checkout
- Place an Order (In short whole front-store)

Now I want these **API's in multi-language**, Any one have achieved the same with Magento 2 or with custom code.

- Only Guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Hi @aditya, you can always put the default store view before "/{store_view_code}/V1/", this will set the store view id and you can manage that

Comment: multi-language From store_view code ? How ? can you please elaborate ?

Comment: let say you two store views (store_en/store_de), if you call this api /store_en/V1/products, then you will retrive all products for the store_en store view, so you only need to put the store code before the /V1/,

Comment: ooh okay, please add as answer :)

Comment: i just answered this below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the store code before the /V1/

For example, let say you have two store views (store_en/store_de), if you call this api /store_en/V1/products, then you will retrive all products for the store_en store view, so you only need to put the store code before the /V1/